# get value inside input for autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

I am workind with a MVC framework cakephp , I need to recover each value written in the input even if when I add character or delete one (you know the purpose of autocpmlete), I have to recover this value in input to send it to the action for generate a json file who contains a list of suggester.

this is my function javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
var autotext;
            $('#searchItem').on("input",function() {
        autotext = $('#divResult').html($(this).val());

            console.log(autotext);
        });
         $('#searchItem').autocomplete({

            data: { mot:autotext },
            source: 'getAutocomplete.json',

           dataType: "json",
            minLength: 2

         }); 

      });
```

nothing happen
[image]

And when I get the value send in data from the input to use it in my controller with :

```
$forsearch=$this->request->data['mot'];
```

I get this ERROR the index 'mot' is Undefined.
How to get the value of input in my controller?

Answer (score 1):

This is the code for getting the value of the input every time the user types something. And then send it to the controller.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#input").keyup(function(){
      console.log($(this).val());

      $.ajax({
        url: "controller",
        type: "get",
        data:{text: $(this).val()},
        success: function(response) {
          //here is where you treat the JSON
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
          //if stuff goes bad
        }
      });  
    });
  });
```

the "#input" is the id of the input field.

I am using ajax to send the input value to the controller.